# SQL: how to only use dynamic column for order, not as part of result set

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I currently have a query that returns a list of columns, and one of those columns I only want to use internally as a sort column, not as a column in the result set.

```
  SELECT Id, Lat, Lng, <haversine calc> as Distance
    FROM Locations
ORDER BY Distance
```

Based on the above, the only reason I currently include 'Distance' in the the SELECT clause is so I can use it in the ORDER BY clause.  My consumer code doesn't use Distance at all.

How can I rewrite this query to only return the columns I'm interested in (Id, Lat, Lng) and not the ones I'm not interested in (Distance), while allowing the sort on Distance?

Comment: Have you tried moving the Haversine formula to the `ORDER BY`?  Some databases support ordering by a column/formula that is not in the `SELECT` clause.  But it'd be good to know what database you are working with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is to move your calculation into your ORDER BY clause like this:

```
SELECT Id, Lat, Lng
FROM Locations
ORDER BY <haversine calc>
```

Comment: Not every database supports ordering by a column not in the `SELECT` clause, but I can't remember which ones ATM.

Comment: That would be an awful limitation. Most syntax definition have the order by listed as `ORDER BY <expression ... etc. ASC | DESC ...>` where the `expression` part can be a column name, alias or any valid SQL expression...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include a column in select cause you want to sort on it. You can directly query the cols you want

```
SELECT Id, Lat, Lng FROM Locations ORDER BY <Your Col>
```